# Java haincode is work-in-progress and disabled

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install Java chaincode from sample hyperledger 1.1.0

on the hyperledgre side inside docker gets next:

```
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 42a Entry
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 42b ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc4202a98f0
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 42c validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 42d checkSignatureFromCreator starts
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 437 Entry
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 438 ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc42025ff80
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.831 UTC [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 439 validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.832 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 43a checkSignatureFromCreator starts
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.833 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 42e checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is &{Org1MSP 9cf4e05a1061cd08f05e5de59f3177756d4cffbdeb1c69b0cc3139292c4eb9f7}
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.833 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 42f checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is valid
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.833 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 43b checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is &{Org1MSP 9cf4e05a1061cd08f05e5de59f3177756d4cffbdeb1c69b0cc3139292c4eb9f7}
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.834 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 430 checkSignatureFromCreator exists successfully
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.834 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 431 validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc42027b130, header 0xc4202a9920
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.834 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 432 validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"lscc" 
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.834 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 433 processing txid: ae37b8c106797915c6c45148637c76c33c11fc83d8a7cc3b41685a99f0d9fe98
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.834 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 434 Entry - txid: ae37b8c106797915c6c45148637c76c33c11fc83d8a7cc3b41685a99f0d9fe98 channel id: 
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.835 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 435 Exit
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.835 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 436 Exit
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.835 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 43c checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is valid
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.836 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 43d checkSignatureFromCreator exists successfully
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.836 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 43e validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc421509680, header 0xc42025ffb0
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.836 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 43f validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"lscc" 
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.836 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 440 processing txid: ae37b8c106797915c6c45148637c76c33c11fc83d8a7cc3b41685a99f0d9fe98
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.837 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 441 Entry - txid: ae37b8c106797915c6c45148637c76c33c11fc83d8a7cc3b41685a99f0d9fe98 channel id: 
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.837 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 442 Exit
peer1.org1.example.com    | 2017-08-22 10:47:07.837 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 443 Exit
```

As you can see do not have any error. But inside the response on the java side get:

```
Sending proposal to peer1.org1.example.com failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=Java chaincode is work-in-progress and disabled, cause=null}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is probably a question for the maintainers of that project

Answer (score 1):

Java Chaincode support has been disabled, because it was incomplete at the time that the 1.0 release of Hyperledger Fabric was being finalized. This was announced with the [v1.0.0-beta release](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta).

If you wish to enable it for experimental purposes, you can clone the Hyperledger Fabric [codebase](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) and reverse [this commit](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/29e0c40)